# Requesting Location permission does not return (Xamarin Forms)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm requesting location permission if it is denied, but nothing is returned after the request is made and the user taps to deny or allow the permission, the line  `status = results[Permission.Location];` is never hit, I thought it would be as it's an awaitable call, can anyone tell me why this is?

I should mention that if I call this code again immediately after it looks like it has done nothing, then line `await vm.RefreshCampaigns();` is hit, so the permission is being set, it's just the call not returning. I'm running this code in the shared project.

```
private async void GrantPermission(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Location);
        if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
        {
            var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.Location);
            status = results[Permission.Location];
        }

        if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
        {
            vm.ShowPermissionWarning = false;
            await vm.RefreshCampaigns();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Crashes.TrackError(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: My experience with async/await in Xamarin has been that it is really fragile and should be avoided.

Comment: I use async/await elsewhere and in other apps and it appears to behave, it just seems to be this method.  In that case, have you any suggestion on how I can set the permission and then know the result?  Thanks

Comment: I am not too familiar with Permissions in Mobile OS-es, but isn't it possible that Permission.Location is denied by the user already, so the OS disallows you from asking for the permission again? Many web browsers work like this, until you specifically remove the block in the browser settings.

The enum has 'Disabled' and 'Denied' values, if I see correctly.

Comment: @iSpain17 if the user initially denies permission on install we can use the plugin Plugin.Permissions to request that permission again, then evaluate the result, either deny or allow.  I have done this many times on app startup (request permission), and have checked the status of the permission many times, but I haven't had to do both before and I assumed I could easily await the result.

Comment: have you got which line of code gets "stuck" in RequestPermissionAsync?

Comment: The line var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync... if I put a breakpoint here and on the next line it never hits the next line

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old and solved now, but I ran into the same issue using Shiny. What worked for me was to add the OnRequestPermissionResult method into the MainActivity. Example below from [Xamarin.Essentials Permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/permissions?tabs=android):

```
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
{
    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```